# javapns sends notification but i receive anything

Tags: notifications, apple-push-notifications, javapns

I can send notification without any error but I don't get anything on my device. I tried a lot of solutions and I don't know what else I can do.

The certificat and token works in PHP...
Configuration : Java 1.8, Tomcat 7, Javapns 2.2

Thanks

**Code**

```
BasicConfigurator.configure();
URL res = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("KeyNotification/certificat.p12");

File f = new File(res.getFile());
List<PushedNotification> notifications = Push.combined("message", 10, "", f.getAbsolutePath(), "password", false, token);

for (PushedNotification notification : notifications) {
    if (notification.isSuccessful()) {
        System.out.println("Push notification sent successfully to: " + notification.getDevice().getToken());
    } else {
        String invalidToken = notification.getDevice().getToken();
        Exception theProblem = notification.getException();
        theProblem.printStackTrace();

        /* If the problem was an error-response packet returned by Apple, get it */
        ResponsePacket theErrorResponse = notification.getResponse();

        if (theErrorResponse != null) {
            System.out.println(theErrorResponse.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**Log**

```
0 [http-bio-8080-exec-21] DEBUG javapns.communication.ConnectionToAppleServer  - Creating SSLSocketFactory
3 [http-bio-8080-exec-21] DEBUG javapns.communication.ConnectionToAppleServer  - Creating SSLSocket to feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com:2196
1189 [http-bio-8080-exec-21] DEBUG javapns.feedback.FeedbackServiceManager  - Found: [0]
1194 [http-bio-8080-exec-21] DEBUG javapns.notification.Payload  - Adding alert [message]
1194 [http-bio-8080-exec-21] DEBUG javapns.notification.Payload  - Adding badge [10]
1194 [http-bio-8080-exec-21] DEBUG javapns.notification.Payload  - Adding sound []
1199 [http-bio-8080-exec-21] DEBUG javapns.communication.ConnectionToAppleServer  - Creating SSLSocketFactory
1201 [http-bio-8080-exec-21] DEBUG javapns.communication.ConnectionToAppleServer  - Creating SSLSocket to gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195
1444 [http-bio-8080-exec-21] DEBUG javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager  - Initialized Connection to Host: [gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com] Port: [2195]: 1e816c94[SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL: Socket[addr=gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com/17.110.227.35,port=2195,localport=63887]]
1447 [http-bio-8080-exec-21] DEBUG javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager  - Building Raw message from deviceToken and payload
1447 [http-bio-8080-exec-21] DEBUG javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager  - Built raw message ID 1 of total length 98
1447 [http-bio-8080-exec-21] DEBUG javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager  - Attempting to send notification: {"aps":{"badge":10,"alert":"message","sound":""}}
1447 [http-bio-8080-exec-21] DEBUG javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager  -   to device: 1d8e0488958b92297923884508bf3714835f3581101ede9d3155ded0d8241c3e
2315 [http-bio-8080-exec-21] DEBUG javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager  - Flushing
2315 [http-bio-8080-exec-21] DEBUG javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager  - At this point, the entire 98-bytes message has been streamed out successfully through the SSL connection
2315 [http-bio-8080-exec-21] DEBUG javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager  - Notification sent on first attempt
2315 [http-bio-8080-exec-21] DEBUG javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager  - Reading responses
7321 [http-bio-8080-exec-21] DEBUG javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager  - Closing connection
Push notification sent successfully to: 1d8e0488958b92297923884508bf3714835f3581101ede9d3155ded0d8241c3e
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem , the certificate was not compatible !

The command line to create the certificate (aps_development.pem is downloaded from Apple, myprivatekey.p12 is exported from my app private key in the "Keychain Access") :

```
openssl x509 -in aps_development.cer -inform DER -out aps_development.pem -outform PEM
openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -in myprivatekey.p12 -out myprivatekey.pem
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey myprivatekey.pem -in aps_development.pem -out cert_dev.p12
```